# Deriving a polylog bound

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logarithms

Reading through a paper and it is stated that $k(1-1/d)^{k-1} < 1$ implies that $k < (1+o(1))d \log d$ without proof (assume $k,d > 1$). How is this fact derived? I assume that the $d \log d$ term comes from $\log(1-1/d) < \log \log d$ but apart from that it is not obvious to me.

Comment: I suggest instead considering the intuition $1-1/d\approx e^{-1/d}$ and taking logarithms of both sides of the assumed inequality.

Comment: $k(1-1/d)^{k-1} > 1$ or $k(1-1/d)^{k-1} < 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi the theorem assumption is < 1 (see Thm 11 in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.07638.pdf))

Comment: @DocStories I think that you misunderstood theorem 11. It should be $k(1 - 1/d)^{k-1} < 1$ implies $k > R(d)$. Note that $\lim_{k\to \infty} k(1-1/d)^{k-1} = 0 < 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi ah, I see. So the assumption implies that $k > R(d)$ but it's still not clear that this further implies $R(d) \le (1 + o(1))d \log d$?

Comment: It needs to be checked, by I guess it works as follows. 
Since $1+x\le e^x$ for each real $x$, it suffices to choose $k$ such that $ke^{-(k-1)/d}<1$.
If $k=(1+o(1))d\log d$ then $ke^{-(k-1)/d}=(1+o(1))(\log d)d^{-o(1)}$.

Comment: @DocStories The first part of Theorem 11 proved $R(d) < k$ for any $k> 1$ satisfying $k(1 - 1/d)^{k-1} < 1$.
For fixed $d > 1$, let $f(d) := \inf \{k \in \mathbb{R}_{> 1} : k(1 - 1/d)^{k-1} < 1\}$. Then we have $R(d)\le f(d)$.
We can prove that $f(d) < (1 + o(1))d\ln d$. This completes the proof.

Comment: @RiverLi ah! I see the logic now. Thank you.

Comment: @DocStories You are welcome.

Comment: According to the discussion, the problem can be rephrased as follows.
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $d > 1$. If $a < k$ for all $k>1$ satisfying $k(1 - 1/d)^{k-1} < 1$, then $a < (1 + o(1))d\ln d$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, the problem can be rephrased as follows.

**Problem.** Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $d > 1$. If $a < k$ for all $k>1$ satisfying $k(1 - 1/d)^{k-1} < 1$, then $a < (1 + o(1))d\ln d$.

**Proof.** Consider $d > 4$. Choose
$$k = \left(1 + \frac{\ln(\ln d) + \frac{1}{d}}{\ln d - 1}\right)d\ln d.$$

We claim that $k(1 - 1/d)^{k - 1} < 1$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
 \ln k + (k - 1)\ln(1 - 1/d)
 &= \ln (d\ln d) + \ln\frac{k}{d\ln d} + (k - 1)\ln(1 - 1/d)\\[6pt]
 &< \ln (d\ln d) + \frac{k}{d\ln d} - 1 + (k - 1)(-1/d)\\[6pt]
 &= 0
\end{align*}
where we use $\ln x \le x - 1$ for all $x > 0$,
and $\ln (1 - 1/d) < -1/d$.

Thus, we have
$$a < \left(1 + \frac{\ln(\ln d) + \frac{1}{d}}{\ln d - 1}\right)d\ln d = (1 + o(1))d\ln d.$$

We are done.

Comment: Already upvote. Nice solution! Btw, could you please think of problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796969/finding-small-max-limits-abbcca-1-dfrac-sqrtabc-sqrtbca-sqrtca?noredirect=1#comment10203442_4796969) help me? Thank you

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks. I will try.