# Finding $\small{\max\limits_{ab+bc+ca=1}\dfrac{\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}}{\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10}} }$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

**Problem.** Given $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Find the maximal value $P$ $$P=\frac{\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}}{\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10}}
.$$

---

When I denote $a=b=1;c=0$ we get $P\le \dfrac{3}{4}.$ We'll prove that is maximal value.

Now, it's enough to prove $$\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\le \frac{3}{4}
\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10}.$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality$$\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\le \sqrt{3(a+b+c+1)}\le \frac{3}{4}
\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10},$$which is true at $\sqrt{3}\le a+b+c\le 2.$

In remain case, $a+b+c>2.$ It suffices to prove $$\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\le 3.$$
I still failed to prove it is true. Hope you help me continue my idea.

Also, does MV (Mixing variables) technique, AM-GM help? Thank you.

Update 1: RiverLi's Cauchy-Schwarz using is very nice but it's still a complicated solution.

Comment: Your idea leads to wrong inequalitity. Check 1 var is to infinity

Comment: Are you sure???

Comment: Yes, check $a=b\rightarrow 0$

Comment: An approach that would never work in a contest but can work in the real world is to use Lagrange multipliers. It would be very messy but with a good CAS and algebraic equation solver still tractable.

Comment: Diid you try Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal What is CAS?

Comment: CAS stands for Computer Algebra System. Examples include Maple, Mathematica, Sympy and Fricas

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal If LM works, we just need to check case two equal variables.

Comment: I wonder if there is a possible approach during contest time.  I tried assume $a\ge b\ge c$ but nothing else

Comment: Hmm, the problem is very tough. Who is this problem belonged?

Comment: @TATAbox It is one of problems in TST China

Comment: @Anonymous So, there is a contest-style solution.

Comment: @RiverLi I hope so.

Comment: @RiverLi I tried Holder without success

Comment: @TATAbox Did you try C-S?

Comment: @RiverLi I'm stuck to find suitable C-S

Comment: @TATAbox C-S works. But it is not nice by hand.

Comment: @RiverLi Could you share it ?

Comment: @RiverLi That would be interesting

Answer (score 3):

**Proof.** It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\le \frac{3}{4}
\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10}$$
or
$$\left(\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\right)^2 \le \frac{9}{16}
(3a+3b+3c+10).\tag{1}$$

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\right)^2\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{a + bc}{23ab + 44bc + 23ca + 23a + 2b + 2c}\right)\\[6pt]
&\qquad \cdot \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (23ab + 44bc + 23ca + 23a + 2b + 2c)\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{a + bc}{23ab + 44bc + 23ca + 23a + 2b + 2c}\right) \cdot 9(3a + 3b + 3c + 10). \tag{2}
\end{align*}

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{a + bc}{23ab + 44bc + 23ca + 23a + 2b + 2c} \le \frac{1}{16}. \tag{3}$$

We use pqr method. Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$. Using $p^2\ge 3q = 3$, we have $p \ge \sqrt 3$.

(3) is equivalently written as
$$-1701\,{r}^{2}+ \left( -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 \right) r + 2(p-2)(2p^2+25p+86)
\ge 0.$$
Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$$-1701\,{r}\cdot \frac{1}{3p}+ \left( -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 \right) r + 2(p-2)(2p^2+25p+86)
\ge 0$$
or
$$\left(-\frac{567}{p} -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 \right) r + 2(p-2)(2p^2+25p+86) \ge 0. \tag{4}$$

We split into two cases.

**Case 1.** $\sqrt 3 \le p \le 2$

Using $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} = \frac{p(4 - p^2)}{9}$ (degree three Schur), using $-\frac{567}{p} -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(-\frac{567}{p} -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 \right) \cdot \frac{p(4 - p^2)}{9}  + 2(p-2)(2p^2+25p+86) \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac13(p - 2)(589p^4 + 231p^3 - 3208p^2 - 2313p + 894) \ge 0$$
which is true.

**Case 2.** $p > 2$

Clearly, we only need to prove the  case that $-\frac{567}{p} -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 < 0$.

From $0 \le (a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 = -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}$, we have
$$r \le - \frac{2}{27} p^3 + \frac{p}{3}
+ \frac{2}{27}(p^2 - 3)\sqrt{p^2 - 3} =: r_2.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(-\frac{567}{p} -1767\,{p}^{2}+2841\,p+3978 \right) \cdot r_2 + 2(p-2)(2p^2+25p+86) \ge 0 \tag{5}$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: C-S using is so magical! Thank a lot

Comment: @Anonymous You are welcome. It is still not a solution during a contest.

Comment: @Anonymous Is there an official solution?

Comment: @RiverLi I've tried to use $p\ge 9r$ without success. Could you give me a hint to full it ?

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks. I will do it soon.

Comment: @RiverLi Nice C-S apply!

Comment: @Dragonboy Thanks. But my proof of the resulting inequality is not nice.

Comment: @Anonymous I added the pqr proof. Honestly, it is not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi Now it is more clear. Thanks. Btw, the problem is hard and your proof is nice enough.

Comment: I honestly don't think there exists a nice proof of such a hard inequality. Very well done, +1! I'm curious if you used a CAS to help with finding the correct usage of CS.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks. It should exist a nice proof since it is a contest problem. Yes, I used Maple.  But it is not difficult by hand.

Comment: This is the best answer here. I accept! Thanks again.

Comment: I tried the problem again yesterday without success. Very hard inequality and good solution enough!

Comment: @TATAbox Sometimes, we eliminate the roots by C-S/Holder etc., the resulting inequality is still complicated.  For example, I used C-S for [this difficult inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686470/prove-that-fx-y-le-3-for-x-ge-0-y-0/4553517#4553517); But the resulting inequality is not easy by hand.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thought.**

I hope the following approach will help.

Assume that $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0.$ Chose $t>0$ such that $t^2+2tc=1.$

It implies that $a\ge t\ge b\ge c$. Now, denote
$$\color{black}{f(a,b,c)=\frac{\sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}}{\sqrt{3a+3b+3c+10}}.}$$
And
$$\color{black}{f(t,t,c)=\frac{2\sqrt{t+tc}+\sqrt{c+t^2}}{\sqrt{6t+3c+10}}.}$$
If we can prove $f(a,b,c)\le f(t,t,c)$ the rest seems smooth by proving $$f(t,t,c)=\frac{2\sqrt{t+t\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t}+t^2}}{\sqrt{6t+3\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t}+10}}\le \frac{3}{4}.$$